# Select data from one table depending on the results of another select SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables that I need to compare to find records that are not in one table.
My SQL so far is,

```
SELECT ORD_NAME FROM ERP_IMPORT_COMP
EXCEPT
SELECT NAME FROM OR_ORDER
```

This returns the ORD_NAME's of the records I want, but I would like to select all the fields in ERP_IMPORT_COMP WHERE they don't exist in OR_ORDER, matching by ORD_NAME=NAME.
Is that possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Be great to see sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like you need to use *not exists*

```
select *
from ERP_IMPORT_COMP c
where not exists (
  select * from OR_ORDER o
  where o.NAME = c.ORD_NAME 
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic case for a `left join`

```
SELECT I.ORD_NAME 
FROM ERP_IMPORT_COMP I
LEFT JOIN OR_ORDER O ON O.NAME = I.ORD_NAME 
WHERE O.NAME IS NULL
```